# Row and columnconfiguration does not have any effect on the window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I'm trying to build a visualisation with buttons and I want it to look a little bit like this
[image]

I was trying to get this kind of layout with python via the .rowconfigure and .columnconfigure, but it doesn't seem to work as any changes I try to make with columnconfigure and rowconfigure do not have any impact on my visualisation in the end. I want row1 to be a little thicker and row8 to be a little thiner than the other rows and I'd like column1 and column2 to have the same thickness, but still being able to resize. When I set minsize instead of weight in the configuration then the resizing is not possible any more. Right now column2 is smaller than column1 and the rows do whatever they want.

If it is helpful, here is what I coded so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("")

root.config(background = "white")
frame = Frame(root, highlightbackground="AntiqueWhite3", highlightcolor="AntiqueWhite3", highlightthickness="5", bg = "white")
i = 0

#frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

def update():
    i = lbl1.winfo_width() + 1

frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

frame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 3)
frame.rowconfigure(1, weight = 2)
frame.rowconfigure(2, weight = 2)
frame.rowconfigure(3, weight = 2)
frame.rowconfigure(4, weight = 2)
frame.rowconfigure(5, weight = 2)
frame.rowconfigure(6, weight = 2)
frame.rowconfigure(7, weight = 1)   

#Elements

lbl_n = Label(frame, text= "Text", font= ("Arial", 20), bg = "white")
lbl_n.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)

btn_hand = Button(frame, text = "Text", bg = "light grey")
btn_hand.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady =5, sticky='nsew')
btn_auto = Button(frame, text = "Text", bg = "light grey")
btn_auto.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady =5, sticky='nsew')

lbl1 = Label(frame, text= "Start", font = ("Arial", 15), bg = "white")
lbl1.grid(row=2, column=0, padx= 10, pady = 3, sticky='nsw')
btn1 = Button(frame, text = "Status", bg = "light grey")
btn1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=20, pady =3, sticky='nsew')

lbl2 = Label(frame, text= "1. Step", font = ("Arial", 15), bg = "white")
lbl2.grid(row=3, column=0, padx= 10, pady = 3, sticky='nsw')
btn2 = Button(frame, text = "Status", bg = "light grey")
btn2.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=20, pady =3, sticky='nsew')

lbl3 = Label(frame, text= "2. Step", font = ("Arial", 15), bg = "white")
lbl3.grid(row=4, column=0, padx= 10, pady = 3, sticky='nsw')
btn3 = Button(frame, text = "Status", bg = "light grey")
btn3.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=20, pady =3, sticky='nsew')

lbl4 = Label(frame, text= "3. Step", font = ("Arial", 15), bg = "white")
lbl4.grid(row=5, column=0, padx= 10, pady = 3, sticky='nsw')
btn4 = Button(frame, text = "Status", bg = "light grey")
btn4.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=20, pady =3, sticky='nsew')

lbl5 = Label(frame, text= "Last Step", font = ("Arial", 15), bg = "white")
lbl5.grid(row=6, column=0, padx= 10, pady = 3, sticky='nsw')
btn5 = Button(frame, text = "Status", bg = "light grey")
btn5.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=20, pady =3, sticky='nsew')

btn6 = Button(frame, text = "STOP", bg = "red", font=("Arial", 10, "bold"), width=15, borderwidth=3)
btn6.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=10, pady =3, sticky='nw')

frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing right now?

Comment: `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` only tell tkinter how to handle _extra_ space. There are other options that can control the width and height, and whether rows are identical in size or not.

Comment: @BryanOakley what other options would that be?

Comment: `uniform`, `pad`, and `minsize`

Comment: But then stretching won't be able anymore

Comment: Why do you say that? Why not try it and see?